# htaccess rewriting same page names conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

My htaccess file has the following two lines

```
RewriteRule ^payment payment.php
RewriteRule ^payment-confirmed payment-confirmed.php
```

When trying to access payment-confirmed.php it just goes to payment.php (payment) - I'm guessing this is because it only reads the first word and thinks it has found the location.

Is there a way I can configure my htaccess file to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three different ways:

1. Use Alias instead of Rewrite:

```
    Alias payment payment.php
    Alias payment-confirmed payment-confirmed.php
```

2. Include a `$`, which means "end of the string":

```
    RewriteRule ^payment$ payment.php
    RewriteRule ^payment-confirmed$ payment-confirmed.php
```

3. Move the lines around, so that the most specific line gets checked first:

```
    RewriteRule ^payment-confirmed$ payment-confirmed.php
    RewriteRule ^payment$ payment.php
```